# PYNQ Z2 : Arduino PINS and HC SR04

Tags: python, fpga

My team mates and I have tried to estimate a distance using the captor HC SR04 (Ultrasonic captor) on PYNQ Z2 board.
We are using the Arduino_IO library.

```
GND -> GND
VCC -> 5V
TRIG -> AR1
ECHO -> AR0
```

This is our script :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K1KN.png)

The main problem is that we get as an output a value that is always close to 0,5 sec between each time capture.

Do you have any ideas why we have this value ?

PS : We have tested similar code on a Arduino Uno and it was working

Regards,
Symbole

Comment: Please add the code in the question rather than a screenshot.

Comment: Python has the keyword `pass` to  avoid things such as your `do_nothing` function

Comment: Have you tried to hook up an oscilloscope to check that you are correctly driving the pins?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that python is too slow for this approach. You have something like

```
while read == 0:
   pass

# A
start = time.time()

# B 
while.read == 1:
   pass

# C
end = time.time()
```

Assume that calling `time()` takes 1 second, and your while takes the echo time, which is between 0.1 and 0.3 seconds. (scale your numbers appropriately)

The measured time is between `[1.1 and 1.3]`. Meaning you'll always get the very same value because your offset is too big and eats up the dynamic of your signal.

You need a different approach maybe with interrupts, because Python is too slow. However you can make this attempt:

```
# on a different notebook do
offset_avg = 0
for i in range(1000):
  s = time.time()
  e = time.time()
  delta = e-s
  offset_avg += delta

offset_avg = offset_avg/1000
```

And now write down the value of the `offset_avg` and "normalize" your calculation

```
dist = round( ( finPulse - inPulse - offset_avg ) * 340 / 2 , 1 )
```

I am curious to see if this makes any difference, or if my guess is totally wrong.